# I'm trying to use XROTOR, need to use a Makefile but ifort: command not found

Tags: cygwin, win64

I am about 3 hours new to Linux/Cygwin/virtually anything even borderline computer science. I have been tasked with installing a program for rotors/propellers for research (XROTOR), but I cannot figure out how to run the program. It seems to have been developed in Fortran (maybe?), and came with a README. The README is asking me to build the file, but I have no clue what that means. I have downloaded Cygwin, and have gotten as far as the "make libPLT.a" line. I then cd'ed to the bin folder, and typed in "make xrotor" like the README states, but I keep getting the following error:

```
$ make
ifort -c -I../src -O -static ../src/xrotor.f
sh: ifort: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:147: xrotor.o] Error 127
```

I've included the README as well. I don't know what I'm doing, and I figured this was a decent place to start. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!!

EDIT: Left the README out for whatever reason, sorry. I've written it out here:

### General

XROTOR and its plot library should compile on any Unix system 
with normal Fortran-77, C, and X-Windows support.  So far,
XROTOR has been tested on the following systems:

DEC-5000
  Alpha
  SGI
* Sun
* RS/6000
* HP-9000
* Pentium/Linux

The systems marked with "*" have peculiar features which require slight 
modifications to the Makefiles in the plotlib/ and bin/ directories.
Examine these Makefiles before building the plot library and Xrotor.

### Build Sequence

To install, first build the plot library in  ./plotlib  ...

% cd plotlib
 % make libPlt.a

Then build the programs in  ./bin  ...

% make xrotor
 % make jplot

Comment: the fortran compiler on cygwin is called `gfortran` from package `gcc-fortran`

Answer (score 0):

The README is missing some details, but you need to compile the program from sources,
and to do so you need to adjust some variables in the `Makefile's`

As prerequisite for compiling you need `gcc-fortran`,`make` and library `libX11-devel` 
plus the X11 system for the graphic. Installing `xinit` is a good start.

```
$ tar -xf Xrotor7.55.tar.tgz
$ cd Xrotor
$ cd plotlib
```

than modify  config.make to set `PLTLIB = libPlt.a`
I used my preferred editor, but other are also ok

```
$ vim config.make
```

To build:

```
$ make libPlt.a
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_base.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_font.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_util.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_color.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  set_subs.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  gw_subs.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  ps_subs.f
gcc -c -O2 -DUNDERSCORE Xwin.c
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_old.f
gfortran -c -O2 -fdefault-real-8  plt_3D.f
ar r     libPlt.a plt_base.o plt_font.o plt_util.o plt_color.o set_subs.o gw_subs.o ps_subs.o Xwin.o plt_old.o plt_3D.o
ar: creating libPlt.a
ranlib  libPlt.a
```

Than moving to program build directory

```
$ cd ../bin
```

again modify `Makefile.gfortran` to set `PLTOBJ = ../plotlib/libPlt.a` and `LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lX11`

```
$ vim Makefile.gfortran
```

and build all program in one shot

```
$ make -f Makefile.gfortran
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/xrotor.f
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/xoper.f
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/xdesi.f
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/xmodi.f
...
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/plotdata.f
gfortran -o xrotor xrotor.o xoper.o xdesi.o xmodi.o  xaero.o xjmap.o xio.o xnoise.o xrotpl.o xcasepl.o xbend.o xinte.o xutils.o jputil.o plutil.o modify.o srclin.o spline.o userio.o vortex.o plotdata.o  ../plotlib/libPlt.a  -L/usr/lib -lX11
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/jplot.f
../src/jplot.f:107:72:

       PAUSE 'Hit return to see J values'
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)
../src/jplot.f:112:72:

       PAUSE 'Hit return to see CP values'
                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)
gfortran -o jplot jplot.o  xutils.o jputil.o userio.o ../plotlib/libPlt.a  -L/usr/lib -lX11
gfortran -c -I../src -O ../src/jplote.f
gfortran -o jplote jplote.o xutils.o jputil.o userio.o ../plotlib/libPlt.a  -L/usr/lib -lX11
```

The Warning means that the PAUSE command does not exist anymore so the progran will
likely not pause on the expected locations.
This could explain why it is not working as expected, but probably as the code is very old some code assumptions about the Unix system are not anymore valid.
Running it after starting the Xwindow graphic system from inside a Xterm

```
$ ./xrotor

 =========================
    XROTOR Version 7.55
 =========================
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
STOP COLORSPECTRUM: Non-monotonic color axis. Check COLWIDTH.
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to edit the COLORSPECTRUMTRP subroutine xrotor/plotlib/plt_color.f. Add the following after line 508

COLWIDTH=(/1.0,1.20000005,0.5,1.4,1.0,1.20000005,1.5/)